# wave equation PDE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, wave-equation

> Solve the initial boundary value problem
>
> \begin{eqnarray}
> u_{tt} &=& u_{xx} + u_t ~~\mbox{in}~~ (0, \ell) \times (0, \infty), \\
> u(0, t) &=& u(\ell, t) ~~\mbox{on}~~ (0, \infty), \\
> u(x, 0) &=& \sin x, ~ u_t(x, 0) = \cos x ~~\mbox{on}~~ (0, \ell).
> \end{eqnarray}

My try :

I directly applied separation of variables, I wasnt able to get the transformation so tat it can be converted to $$w_{tt} = w_{xx}$$ and i solved Time second degree ODE using characteristic equation.
I used Boundary conditions , but when i try to implement intital i am not sure how to implement the last condition.

My form so far after applying BCs :
$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(n\pi x/l)[c_1 e^{\frac t2(1+\sqrt{1-4(\frac{n\pi}{l})^2})} + c_2 e^{\frac t2(1-\sqrt{1-4(\frac{n\pi}{l})^2})}]$$

Comment: Multiply by $\sin(m \pi x /l)$ on both sides and integrate w.r.t. $x$

Comment: in which ??? solution or orignal pde ?

Comment: i dont think u are right what u are saying i already solved using inverse fourier to get c_1 + c_2 in terms on n and l ,, but i need to apply the last equation ..... or if u can simplify it in wxx = wtt then it will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far you have

$$
u(x, t) = \sum_n \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\right)\left[ A_n e^{\lambda_+ t} + B_n e^{\lambda_- t} \right] \tag{1}
$$

where

$$
\lambda_\pm = \frac{1}{2}\left[1 \pm \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{2n\pi}{l}\right)^2}\right]
$$

Now consider the initial conditions

> $u(x, 0)$

Replacing that in (1) you get

$$
\sin x = \sum_n \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\right) [A_n + B_n]
$$

and from here

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^l {\rm d}x~ \sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right) \sin x &=& \sum_n [A_n + B_n] \int_0^l {\rm d}x~\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\right) \sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right) \\
&=& \sum_{n}[A_n + B_n] \left(\frac{l}{2}\delta_{mn}\right) \\
&=& \frac{l}{2}(A_m + B_m) \\
&=& \frac{l m \pi}{l^2 - m^2\pi^2} \cos(m\pi)\sin l \\
&=& (-1)^m\frac{l m \pi}{l^2 - m^2\pi^2} \sin l
\end{eqnarray}

So in summary

$$
A_m + B_m = (-1)^m\frac{2 m \pi}{l^2 - m^2\pi^2} \sin l \tag{2}
$$

> $u_t(x, 0)$

I will leave this one to you, you should get something like

$$
\lambda_+ A_m + \lambda_- B_m = \cdots \tag{3}
$$

Equations (2) and (3) can be solved to find $A_n$ and $B_n$